# How to send state data via POST request in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, http, axios, vuex

**Background**: I have have a Vuex state object called *'expense'* that is updated via form input fields in a '*form component*'. I need to send that 'expense' object via POST

**Problem:**  I set up an Action that makes the POST request. However the '*expense*' object stored in the state is not being sent.

**PS:** The POST request is successful but the response proves that its not sending the data.

**The response data:**

[image]

**Store State**

```
const mainURI = "/api/budget";

const expenseObj = {
  expensesKey: "",
  expensesValue: null,
  subExpense: null,
};

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    earnings: null,
    expenses: [
      {
        expensesKey: "",
        expensesValue: null,
        subExpense: null,
      },
    ],
  },
```

**Store Action**

```
  actions: {
    addBudget({commit},{ expenses, earnings }) {
      axios
        .post(mainURI, {
          earnings: earnings,
          expenses: expenses,
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
            let newExpense = res.data;
           commit("SUBMIT_BUDGET", newExpense);
        });
    },
  },
```

**Store Methods**

```
  mutations: {
    SUBMIT_BUDGET: (state, payload) => state.newBudget.push(payload),
    UPDATE_EARNINGS: (state, earnings) => state.earnings = earnings;
    UPDATE_KEYS(state, payload) {
      Vue.set(
        state.expenses[payload.index],
        "expensesKey",
        payload.expenseKeyValue
      );
    },
    UPDATE_VALUE(state, payload) {
      Vue.set(
        state.expenses[payload.index],
        "expensesValue",
        payload.expenseValueValue
      );
    },
  },
});
```

**The form componenet**

```
computed:{
 earnings: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.earnings;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit("UPDATE_EARNINGS", value);
      },
    },
},
 methods: {
    submitBudget() {
      this.$store.dispatch("addBudget");
      console.log("triggers");
    },
    updateKey(event, idx) {
      const val = {
        expenseKeyValue: event.target.value,
        index: idx,
      };
      this.$store.commit("UPDATE_KEYS", val);
    },
    updateValue(event, idx) {
      const val = {
        expenseValueValue: event.target.value,
        index: idx,
      };
      this.$store.commit("UPDATE_VALUE", val);
    },
  }
```

Comment: A response can't prove anything about what's being sent. Instead check the Network tab in dev tools to see exactly what is being sent.

Comment: In your 'addBudget' action that sends the POST, have you verified that 'earnings' and 'expenses' contain the values you assume?  Also, consider modifying your 'addBudget' action to take 'earnings' and 'expenses' as a payload.  Lastly, I see a Vue warning in your console log about using a component id 'form'.  Not sure if this is contributing to the problem.

Comment: @shob Thanks for the response! When I checked the network, I gives me a status of 200 but the request payload is empty

Comment: @Tim  Appreciate the feedback! After I checked the network nothing is being sent. So I assume the problem lies that 'earnings' and 'expense' does not contain the values.  The thing that is confusing me is that in Vue DevTools they are getting updated when after user input in the form.  How do I take those state properties as a payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you dispatch the `addBudget` action, there is no payload such as:

```
this.$store.dispatch('addBudget', objectPayload);
```

Maybe that's because you intend to use `earnings` and `expenses` from `state`.  If so, you can remove the payload argument and access `state` from the action context:

```js
actions: {
  addBudget({ state, commit }) {
    axios.post(mainURI, {
      earnings: state.earnings,
      expenses: state.expenses,
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      let newExpense = res.data;
      commit("SUBMIT_BUDGET", newExpense);
    });
  },
},
```